# Is "illicit" the same as "sinful"?

Tags: catholicism, canon-law, law

I understand that certain acts in Catholicism are considered "illicit," or in violation of church law. Is this equivalent to saying that the acts are sinful?

Can something be sinful but not illicit, or illicit but not sinful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Illicit" is a term of Canon Law.

> [ILLICIT](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34074)
>
> That which is unlawful, or contrary to established prescriptions, but not necessarily invalid. Thus, according to ecclesiastical law many elements are prescribed, but not all (or most of them) are strictly necessary for a valid act or, in the sacraments, valid administration. (Etym. Latin *illicitus*, not allowed, forbidden, unlawful; from *licere*, to be permitted.)

Canon Law does not judge sinfulness—as Canon Law only deals with the [external forum](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33485&randomterm=false), and not all sins are public.

Comment: Thank you! So not all sins are illicit, but all illicit acts are sinful?

Comment: @Someone "_all illicit acts are sinful_" Not necessarily. Sometimes one must practice [legal equity (_epikeia_)](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS120.html#SSQ120OUTP1)—when following the letter of the law is more harmful than not following the law.

Comment: The key which the quote hints at is that illicit is often contrasted with invalid. An illicit but valid act is one done contrary to norms of the law but is the act actually occurred. An invalid act is not actually completed (e.g. invalid marriage is no marriage; an illicit but valid marriage results in a real married couple but some circumstance was contrary to law).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to answer this by defining what sin is in the first place.

*Sin is going against God's commandment*

There you have your answer, sin is counted when commandments issued by **God** are violated but not when someone trespasses some law given by a man.

The reason why going against law set by man is not a sin is because God is not a man and vice versa. A man can have interests at heart before giving out a certain law but God is forever impartial.

Comment: The question is both tagged Catholicism and references Catholic canon law, yet your answer makes no reference to Catholic theological understanding. Do you have any references to support that?

Comment: @eques, And catholicism is a subset denomination within Christianity. Sin is defined in relation to God not according to things man has defined or come up with in his or her mind

Comment: Your first point is arguably correct; your second is little more than restating your answer, which suggests you missed the point of my comment. Denominational disputes are fundamentally off-topic, so answers to this question must be in relation to Catholicism and not to some generic/non-specific version of Christianity.  Your answer also hints (perhaps unintentionally) at a form of Christian anarchy, namely that one can morally ignore all human authority because it's never sinful to do so.

Comment: @eques, believe me I tell ye, there is no human authority that does not come from the father. There is no morality that's not already written down by God.

Comment: @eques, good and morals source from God and not man. A man may say it's bad not to sacrament but is it really true?

Comment: Are you new here? Or do you simply choose to ignore the rules of the site? At no point did I assert that there is a morality not from God, but you are still making claims that a) don't entirely follow from your premise and b) don't actually follow what the Catholic church understands by morality in relation to authority